# Simple Restclient POST issue

Tags: c#, post, get, httpwebrequest

Been searching for hours for an answer and cant seem to find anything. I am trying to update from a Windows forms project to a Web Service using Rest client. I have successfully managed to "GET" into a Datagridview, but i am having trouble using "POST". Here is a snippet of the code i am trying to use (Generate License is a method that writes it to  a xml document and returns the stream):

EDIT: The HttpResponse is giving me this error:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Licenses_table><Licenses><ErrorCode>HY000</ErrorCode><DriverCode>1364</DriverCode><Message>Field 'Code' doesn't have a default value</Message></Licenses></Licenses_table>

string Url = "http://localhost:8810/ReplicationService.php/Licenses/";

byte[] dataByte = GenerateLicense(Code, Version1, Name);

HttpWebRequest POSTrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);

POSTrequest.Method = "POST";

POSTrequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
POSTrequest.KeepAlive = false;
POSTrequest.Timeout = 5000;

POSTrequest.ContentLength = dataByte.Length;

Stream POSTstream = POSTrequest.GetRequestStream();

POSTstream.Write(dataByte, 0, dataByte.Length);
```

Comment: To me it sounds as if the problem your generated data which you don't show that causes a validation error on the server. Could you post the stack trace and preferably also the request body?

Comment: Can you post the code for the GET request that worked?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#". That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 0):

Is that the whole code you are showing? I dont see where you are closing the request stream, and then calling GetResponse() on the WebRequest?